# Is there a way to check history of work logged by a specific user in JIRA?

Tags: jira

We ( in our project team) follow regular practice of leaving comments in an jira issue and regularly log the work done.

I want to check the history of work logged by a specific user (or by me) stating the hours worked on a day, and some more useful information.

Is that possible in Jira?

Comment: What version of JIRA?  IIRC, comments won't give you anything, it's if your office uses the work started/ended & issue assignment...

Comment: Jira version 3.1, we do use started/ended and also do log the work done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the [Time Sheet report plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/TIME/JIRA+Timesheet+Plugin): it will list the time logged for a particular project for a particular user over a range of days.